# adding NSMutableArray in every element of an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 2 `NSMutableArray` they are holderArray and dataArray, holderArray will hold the data/objects from the dataArray,
like, `dataArray = {1,2,3,4,5};` -> will be added to `holderArray[0]` and then when i removeAllObject of the dataArray and then added a new data into it i want that data to be saved into `holderArray[2]` and then so on .

where,

```
int increment = 0;

[holderArray[increment] addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];
holderArray[increment] = dataArray;
```

There is an action to add data into the dataArray and then there is also an action(button) to remove all object in it. I hope this is brief enough. And needed help.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: This is not a question. You've told us what you want to do, now we need to know where you're stuck and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, given you have the **dataArray** and the **holderArray** in you class already *initialized*, and given you hook the two buttons to these actions, something like this could work if I got the problem right:

```
- (IBAction)emptyDataArray
{
    [self.dataArray removeAllObjects];
}


- (IBAction)saveDataArray
{
    NSArray *newData = // Here put the data you want to add
    [self.dataArray addObjects:newData];
    [self.holderArray insertObject:[self.dataArray copy] atIndex:self.holderArray.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line code:

```
[tempArray insertObject:dataArray atIndex:increment]
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
NSMutableArray *dataObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *holderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        [holderArray addObject:@"1"];
        [holderArray addObject:@"2"];

        [holderArray addObject:dataObjects];
        [holderArray removeAllObjects];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *holderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=5; j++) {
        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j]];
    }
    [holderArray addObject:dataArray];
    [dataArray removeAllObjects];
}

//If Non ARC don't forget to release the array objects
[holderArray release];
[dataArray release];
```

> Description: Outer loop will run for five times to add 5 array objects i.e. dataArray, innter loop will  also run five times to add {1,2,3,4,5} in dataArray. After adding dataArray in holderArray, we're removing all objects from dataArray to add values again.